# How to Avoid Duplicate Data RestfulApi Laravel

Tags: laravel, flutter

i am creating restful api using laravel while I was viewing the courses list duplicated content was displaying. How to avoid the duplicated data.in order to solved the problem i used DISTINCT but it wasn't works.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Java Basic","contentsname":"Java Introduction"},{"id":1,"name":"Java Basic","contentsname":"Java Variable"},{"id":2,"name":"JDBC","contentsname":"Connecting JDBC"}]
```

i attched the api above while view the flutter it was displayed two times.**Java Basic** i attached screenshot image below.
[image]

what i tried in laravel i attched below of the code.

```
 $courses = Course::select('courses.id', 'courses.name', 'contents.name as contentsname')
        ->join('contents', 'contents.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')->distinct()
        ->get();

        return response()->json($courses);
```

why distinct() in not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can anyway use `groupBy` to get the unique rows by column, In your eloquent query you can do like this,

```
 $courses = Course::select('courses.id', 'courses.name', 'contents.name as contentsname')
        ->join('contents', 'contents.course_id', '=', 'courses.id')
        ->groupBy("courses.name")
        ->get();
```

`groupBy` is actually fetching the distinct values, in fact the `groupBy` will categorize the same values, so that we can use aggregate functions on them. but in this scenario we have no aggregate functions, we are just selecting the value which will cause the result to have distinct values

Comment: got the error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'u338384676_dbsms.courses.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `courses`.`id`, `courses`.`name`, `contents`.`name` as `contentsname` from `courses` inner join `contents` on `contents`.`course_id` = `courses`.`id` group by `courses`.`name`)

Comment: @JohnPeter,`\DB::statement("SET SQL_MODE=''");`  put this line before your query